# Position sticky not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I'm using a sticky footer. By default the footer was `position:fixed`. When the page reaches bottom it will changes to `position:sticky`.

It was working fine in chrome and firefox. But not working in IE11. Still remain as `position:fixed` even after reached the footer. I think whether `sticky` was not supported by IE11 or not. Does i have any solution for this.

Check below code:

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  checkOffset();
});

function checkOffset() {
  if ($('#sticky').offset().top + $('#sticky').height() >=
    $('.bottom_two').offset().top - 10)
    $('#sticky').css({
      'position': 'sticky',
      'transiton': 'position 0.4s'
    });
  if ($(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight <
    $('.bottom_two').offset().top)
    $('#sticky').css({
      'position': 'fixed',
      'transiton': 'position 0.4s'
    }); // restore when you scroll up
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sticky" class="stick">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="bo_wrap">
      <div class="bo_wrap_left">
        <a class="bot_down testride" href="#buy_ride"></a>
        <a class="bot_down downl" href="#" target="_blank"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="clear_both"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bottom_two">
  <div class="container">
    <p>company 2017. all rights reserved.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, it's not supported https://caniuse.com/#search=Sticky

Comment: It's **not Supported in IE11**  You can use [Polyfill](https://css-tricks.com/stickybits-alternative-position-sticky-polyfills/#article-header-id-1)

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please complete it to make a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug in IE. [Read here](http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/802625/min-height-and-flexbox-flex-direction-column-dont-work-together-in-ie-10-11-preview)  and [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky)

You can try using flex or flexbox but it's not official W3C, you can try with something like  `flex: 1 0 auto;`

Or something like `position: fixed; bottom: 0`

Quick search gives up this thread in github, read [here](https://github.com/philipwalton/solved-by-flexbox/issues/28)

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position, position sticky doesn't seem to be supported by IE11.

Comment: Ok. Any alternate solutions